# unable to delete character from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reactjs, input

I am debugging a project built by someone else and there's this strange issue where one of the form boxes cannot delete the last character.

The code uses two JS files, one mostly with React and the other with jQuery (I heard it was a legacy project that got outsourced and someone else just put react on top of it).

Now, because the code is 8000 lines long, it's been relatively difficult for me to debug (especially when they name everything the same...).

I was wondering if anyone would have any pointers?  I checked the state and I can see that the value of the form input is changing (if the word "hello" is there and I delete all the way to "h" and delete again, "h" still stays in the box, but "h" is gone from the "value" field and from the state).

I suspected that it was a jQuery issue, but I do not see anything modifying the form input field values.

Another thing I've noticed is that I cannot CTRL + Delete or Highlight all and Delete at all (it works for the other boxes).

Here's a snippet of the React code for the input.

```
render: function() {
    if( this.state.theData.length ) {

        return (
            <div id="to-airport-wrapper" className="wrapper">
              <label htmlFor="to-airport" className="clear-inline-block">
                  {LEXICON.to}
                <span className="sr-only">{LEXICON.cityOrAirport}</span>
                <span id="wcag-to-airport" className="sr-only">{LEXICON.wcagFromToAirportLabel}</span>
                <ToAirportLabel hasError={this.state.error}/>
              </label>
              <div id={"TO_LAW_"+this.props.groupIndex} className="list-airport-wrapper">
                  <input type="text" id="to-airport" className="from-to-airport full-width" name="to-airport"
                         onFocus={this.onFocus} onChange={this.change} placeholder={LEXICON.cityOrAirport}
                         aria-required="true" aria-autocomplete="list" autoComplete="off"
                         data-airportcode={this.state.airportcode} value={this.state.value}/>
                <ul data-type="to-airport" className="list-airport list-unstyled">
                    {
                        this.state.data.map(function(item, i) {
                            return <li key={i} className="list-airport-item" data-shortname={item.shortName} data-airportcode={item.airportCode} tabIndex="-1"><span>{item.name}</span></li>
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        );

    } else {

        return (
            <div id="to-airport-wrapper" className="wrapper">
              <label htmlFor="to-airport" className="clear-inline-block">{LEXICON.to}</label>
              <div className="list-airport-wrapper">
                <input type="text" id="to-airport" className="from-to-airport full-width" name="to-airport" onChange={this.change} disabled="true" aria-autocomplete="list" data-airportcode="" placeholder={LEXICON.cityOrAirport} autoComplete="off" value="" />
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Here's the Change function:

```
  change: function(event) {

    GLOBAL.ToAirportSetAirportCode('', '');

    console.log("TO VALUE!", event.target.value)

    if( event.target.value ) {
        var jsObjects = this.state.theData;
        var result = jsObjects.filter(function( obj ) {
            var airportName = obj.name.replace('(','\\(').replace(')','\\)');
            var eventTargetValue = event.target.value.replace('(','\\(').replace(')','\\)');
            return airportName.toLowerCase().search( eventTargetValue.toLowerCase() ) !== -1;
        });
        if( result.length > 0 ) {
            $("#TO_LAW_"+this.props.groupIndex+ " ul").show();
            this.setState({
                data: result,
                value:event.target.value
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                value:event.target.value
            });
            $("#to-airport + ul").hide();
        }
    } else {
        this.setState({
            data: this.state.theData,
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

    if( event.target.value == "" || result.length == 0 ) {
        this.reset(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

The console.log for the TO VALUE disappears prematurely when I try to delete the last character in the form input.

Comment: You have several input fields and other markup in your attached code. Can you remove the irrelevant fields and only keep what's relevant to your issue?